# Teams is not displaying my unfurl response

Tags: microsoft-teams

I have a Teams integration with link unfurling set up. I have the messaging endpoint pointed to a public ngrok URL and ngrok proxying a local node.js server that returns the example payload Microsoft has in it's documentation.

This is my endpoint (express.js):

```
app.post('/bot-test', (req, res) => {
  res.send({
    "composeExtension": {
      "type": "result",
      "attachmentLayout": "list",
      "attachments": [
        {
          "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.teams.card.o365connector",
          "content": {
            "sections": [
              {
                "activityTitle": "[85069]: Create a cool app",
                "activityImage": "https://placekitten.com/200/200"
              },
              {
                "title": "Details",
                "facts": [
                  {
                    "name": "Assigned to:",
                    "value": "[Larry Brown](mailto:larryb@example.com)"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "State:",
                    "value": "Active"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  });
});
```

When I post a URL in a message in Teams, I see it POST to that endpoint and it responds without errors, but nothing shows up in Teams. What's going wrong? I can't find any logs on Microsoft's side either. I would expect that Teams renders a card with the response payload.

Comment: Not sure if it will work. Did you authenticate the request before sending it?

Comment: My server is not sending any requests, just responding to teams link unfurl request. Are you saying I have to authenticate/sign my response payload somehow?

Comment: Can you please check with this sample [55.teams-link-unfurling](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/javascript_nodejs/55.teams-link-unfurling). This way it is much easier to handle link unfurl requests.

Comment: Hi did you tried the sample shared? Can you share updates?

Comment: Could you please confirm if your issue has resolved with above suggestion or still looking for any help?

Comment: Sorry, for the late reply, I was out on Christmas break. I was approaching this Teams integration like I did a Slack integration where a large library isn't needed to quickly getting a working implementation. I see now that leaning more on the MS SDK will make it easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Office 365 Connector cards are not supported for link unfurls ("Message extension previews" in MS parlance). Changing the response to a supported card type worked. Unfortunately, MS doesn't surface this problem anywhere and it just silently discards the response. I was able to find a somewhat useful error description by inspecting the network request that went out from the Teams web client, however.

See this for supported card types: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-reference